# How can I remove items with similar productName?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this script which puts every product into the value "all" and then displays them but how can I make it so it doesn't display duplicates of the same product?

For example: I have the same product under different categories but I only want to display one of them within the all category, this is my script.

```js
function filterProduct(value) {

    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button-value");
    buttons.forEach((button) => {

      if (value.toUpperCase() == button.innerText.toUpperCase()) {
        button.classList.add("active");
      } else {
        button.classList.remove("active");
      }
    });

    let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

    elements.forEach((element) => {

      if (value == "all") {
        element.classList.remove("hide");
      } else {

        if (element.classList.contains(value)) {

          element.classList.remove("hide");
        } else {

          element.classList.add("hide");
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

I tried many different things but I really couldn't get it to work, I'm basically stuck at zero right now.

Comment: Can you post the html aswell?

Comment: It looks like you're using DOM as a data storage for your script. Don't do that, instead, implement a JS model, which can keep all kind of meta data, and use the DOM for viewing purposes only.

Comment: Why not store the products in an array, and then filter out the duplicates?